# Make subscription to poem on latex with poemscol

Tags: latex

I am trying to make a poetry collection with latex using the poemscol package. How can I add a subscription with date to each poem? I tried a `\textnote`, but it seems it works otherwise.

Comment: Can you add a bit more of what you tried and why it did not work? We cannot really see the research you have done to solve the problem yourself. HAve you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232461/how-to-simplify-writing-a-book-of-poetry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the command \poemendnote will do what you want (if what you want is to put the publication date underneath the poem). I will add a dedicated command to do this to the next version, I think (it may distinguish between composition date and first publication date too, come to think of it), but I don't know when I will get around to doing that.

Comment: Correction: \poemendnote will append the line number to the note. You should use \literalpoemendnote. Here are more detailed instructions: just after \begin{poem} issue \makepoemendnotes. This will open an external file for poemendnotes for the poem. Then issue \literalpoemendnote{1947} (where 1947 is the date). This will write the date on that file.  Just after you issue \end{poem} issue \putpoemendnotes. This will read the external file back in.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, now it works fine. Also thank you for your great job on poemscol!=)

Answer (score 0):

I have just uploaded a new version of poemscol which has a command \poemdate.
This will place the date one \bigskip under the left margin of the verse block, whether the verse block is at the left of the page, or whether it is centered on the longest line. The new version should make be posted on CTAN and make its way to the mirror sites in the next few days.